# Odoo 11 - Filter products by company

Tags: filter, odoo, odoo-11

I'm trying to include in the website shop a filter by company, but I'm not sure if I can do it without developing some module.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: You want filter in POS or website ?

Comment: Website. Sorry for the misunderstand